# iPXE sanboot starts slowly with " Did not receive response to NOPIN on CID"

Tags: iscsi, targetcli

Environment:
 - CentOS 7 with kernel 3.10.0-1062.18.1.el7.x86_64
 - targetcli version 2.1.fb49
 - isc-dhcpd-4.2.5
 - iPXE version 1.20.1+ and 1.0.0+

I have a CentOS 7 server which can serve Window 10 boot over iSCSI with on-board 1G ethernet port and It worked very well.  After installing SFP+ 10G card on the server, everything looks fine but iPXE sanboot delays about 1 minute and the server's targetcli  log shows the error message, "**Did not receive response to NOPIN on CID**: 0, failing connection for I_T Nexus ,i,0x400027237473,,t,0x01".

I can't see any information about the error message.
Could you explain what it means and how to resolve it?

Comment: This kind of thing could be an MTU problem.  When you went to 10G Ethernet, did your host end up on a different subnet that was configured for jumbo frames?

Comment: @MikeAndrews No. I did not configured anything for jumbo frames.('ip link' tells MTU is 1500 for 10G NIC.) FYI, the switch is a unmanaged one. And all clients and server are in the same LAN.

Comment: @sohnman Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: As mentioned this sounds like a packet issue, best is to use tcpdump or wireshark to try and figure out what is going on at the wire.
Also full output of `ifstat` and details of which iPXE binary is used could help (maybe it is a NIC driver issue, but no way to tell without more info) iPXE could also be built with DEBUG=iscsi enabled, but tcpdumps are usually more useful in cases of iSCSI issues.